# Fix the figure labels in saved images

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, savefig

I'm trying to save a image, but the xlabels doesn't appears in saved image. I tried to modify the size figure, it works but the image become large. I would like to maintain the size and in some way show the complete plot information.

The data is follow.

```
data = {'neighbourhood': ['Allston-Brighton', 'Jamaica Plain', 'South End', 'Back Bay', 'Fenway/Kenmore', 'South Boston', 'Dorchester', 'Beacon Hill', 'North End', 'East Boston', 'Roxbury', 'Mission Hill', 'Charlestown', 'Chinatown', 'West End', 'Roslindale', 'West Roxbury', 'Theater District', 'Downtown Crossing', 'Hyde Park', 'Mattapan', 'Financial District', 'Somerville', 'Leather District', 'Downtown', 'Brookline', 'Cambridge', 'Chestnut Hill', 'Government Center', 'Harvard Square'], 'latitude': [42.35136861184197, 42.311768379852126, 42.342302581102956, 42.349542747362186, 42.34487223416756, 42.33920029843584, 42.30534371604848, 42.35916242461033, 42.36509251919781, 42.374797033371614, 42.32734681549604, 42.331789902337285, 42.378479634468505, 42.35070490587777, 42.36437167301179, 42.2844848817822, 42.28049169547555, 42.35179317067222, 42.355582834130146, 42.25870128503825, 42.286757258759295, 42.35833367767067, 42.38454210544948, 42.35075084496441, 42.358667722753495, 42.34150237882493, 42.36332342051593, 42.30072382305316, 42.3615193534256, 42.373740039980646], 'longitude': [-71.13980032939199, -71.11023629181607, -71.07406928489343, -71.08014985459491, -71.09639276028551, -71.04673010039227, -71.05980648703859, -71.06722209902804, -71.05435502753697, -71.03063773314375, -71.08533342932748, -71.10338968538669, -71.063939091515, -71.06158442474035, -71.06532504101003, -71.13144270905727, -71.15526404132471, -71.06424189076172, -71.0605365814764, -71.11810073342608, -71.0849389578363, -71.0536411757789, -71.08132624190405, -71.05746407735042, -71.05685306951624, -71.12512826846925, -71.10800606379425, -71.1623118265295, -71.06098895883044, -71.12200210465183], 'dist': [5.217274918890407, 5.117420577499391, 0.9157635862891802, 0.3306405006707467, 1.7610810938591674, 2.726903121754893, 5.1844408677649945, 1.227497247961104, 2.4324110127231613, 4.627284517560583, 2.6651506889743173, 3.0369798718044314, 3.283137336413658, 1.2079270532681, 1.7966687812416413, 8.611569508167042, 10.120811029410335, 1.0015368567582976, 1.4167815087370315, 10.751692511599911, 7.105621710489037, 2.059024017017853, 3.818876664289385, 1.546321543507951, 1.842593010462582, 4.130981378134085, 2.975557190604119, 8.966614609646907, 1.7636863017118727, 4.5639916116404695], 'price': [52.70595169067383, 78.32887268066406, 116.85491943359375, 154.3334503173828, 81.05461883544922, 112.77129364013672, 65.13931274414062, 122.6712646484375, 110.73733520507812, 87.53361511230469, 100.67787170410156, 44.86083984375, 109.29198455810547, 97.78974151611328, 172.12989807128906, 68.67533111572266, 70.07238006591797, 103.89393615722656, 92.42691802978516, 32.06399917602539, 59.09000015258789, 51.484615325927734, 56.128204345703125, 170.1875, 64.60416412353516, 21.53333282470703, 134.6619110107422, 58.25, 262.4222106933594, 0.0], 'count': [364, 314, 298, 291, 249, 216, 195, 174, 125, 117, 116, 103, 79, 78, 68, 50, 35, 33, 26, 25, 20, 13, 13, 8, 8, 8, 7, 4, 3, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfc_dist_sort = df.sort_values(by=['count'],ascending=False)
```

I'm working with this code. What can I do to save the image with no head break. I can share my image if necessary, just let me know.

```
x = dfc_dist_sort['neighbourhood']
y = dfc_dist_sort['price']
z = dfc_dist_sort['count']
w = dfc_dist_sort['dist']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True,figsize=(8, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

axs[0].set_title('Comparing price, count and distance mean between neighbourhood')
axs[0].bar(x, y)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Price')
axs[1].bar(x, z)
axs[1].set_ylabel('Count')
axs[2].bar(x, w)
axs[2].set_ylabel('Distance (km)')
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.savefig('comp.png', dpi = 300)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After try others way, I found this:

```
plt.savefig('comp2.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 100)
```

Add the param bbox_inches.

Comment: You can also use `tight_layout` or `constrained_layout` to adjust the axes size so the labels fit (rather than changing the figure size)